# FFmpeg video has an excessively long duration

Tags: javascript, video, ffmpeg, ytdl

When using ytdl-core and ffmpeg-static to download high quality youtube videos, the output video is supposedly thousands of hours long, which makes it not let me advance the video in a media player. The error only occurs in windows 10 players. In VLC or Discord it does not happen.

```
        res.header("Content-Disposition", `attachment;  filename=video.mp4`)

        let video = ytdl(link, {
            filter: 'videoonly'
        })
        let audio = ytdl(link, {
            filter: 'audioonly',
            highWaterMark: 1 << 25
        });
        const ffmpegProcess = cp.spawn(ffmpeg, [
            '-i', `pipe:3`,
            '-i', `pipe:4`,
            '-map', '1:0',
            '-map', '0:0',
            '-vcodec', 'libx264',
            '-c:v', 'libx264',
            '-c:a', 'aac',
            '-crf', '27',
            '-preset', 'veryslow',
            '-b:v', '1500k',
            '-b:a', '128k',
            '-movflags', 'frag_keyframe+empty_moov',
            '-f', 'mp4',
            '-loglevel', 'error',
            '-',
        ], {
            stdio: [
                'pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe',
            ],
        });
    
        video.pipe(ffmpegProcess.stdio[3]);
        audio.pipe(ffmpegProcess.stdio[4]);
        ffmpegProcess.stdio[1].pipe(res);
    
        let ffmpegLogs = ''
    
        ffmpegProcess.stdio[2].on(
            'data',
            (chunk) => {
                ffmpegLogs += chunk.toString()
            }
        )
    
        ffmpegProcess.on(
            'exit',
            (exitCode) => {
                if (exitCode === 1) {
                    console.error(ffmpegLogs)
                }
            }
        )
```

I've tried changing the codecs options. But I'm not sure what I'm doing